# PayPal Billing Plan Key Response Error

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, woocommerce, paypal-rest-sdk

```
function testing(){  
         $headers_array_sub_new = array("X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID" => 'testing',
        "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD" => '12345645',
        "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE" => 'Ab2145sdfd-IhWqUntNLtS4AWDawDzjOUVWjw6nXIcMtyOrkmDu',
        "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID" => 'APP-80W284485P519543T',
        "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT" => "NV",
        "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT" => "JSON",
        "Authorization" =>array('clientId'=>'testing','secret'=>'testing'),
        "Accept" =>'application/json',
             );
  $url = "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/billing-plans";

       $subscriptionplan = array(

             'name'=>'T shirt Plan',
             'description'=> 'welcome plan',
             'type'=> 'INFINITE' ,
             'payment_definitions'=>array('name'=>'welcome','type'=>'REGULAR','frequency_interval'=>'2','frequency'=>'Month','cycles'=>'10','amount'=>'100'),
             'merchant_preferences'=>''
    );

$pay_result_trial = wp_remote_request($url, array('method' => 'POST', 'timeout' => 20, 'headers' => $headers_array_sub_new, 'body' => $subscriptionplan)); 
//$pay_result_trial2 = wp_remote_request($url2, array('method' => 'POST', 'timeout' => 20, 'headers' => $headers_array_sub1, 'body' =>$subscriptionplan)); 
var_dump($pay_result_trial);
```

here is the response error

```
array(5) { ["headers"]=> array(7) { ["server"]=> string(17) "Apache-Coyote/1.1" ["proxy_server_info"]=> string(57) "host=slcsbplatformapiserv3002.slc.paypal.com;threadId=322" ["paypal-debug-id"]=> string(13) "c764b1af30167" ["content-type"]=> string(16) "application/json" ["content-length"]=> string(1) "0" ["date"]=> string(29) "Fri, 20 Mar 2015 05:25:30 GMT" ["connection"]=> string(5) "close" } ["body"]=> string(0) "" ["response"]=> array(2) { ["code"]=> int(401) ["message"]=> string(12) "Unauthorized" } ["cookies"]=> array(0) { } ["filename"]=> NULL ?>



}
```

Can any one help me?

Comment: Be specific on what you ask

Comment: @utility  I am Trying to Paypal Subscription first now going to create plan for billing how to make above code only  i am try.

Comment: `401 Unauthorized`...Check your credentials again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the right credentials for the call.  You are using your API User/Pwd/Signature which are used for the Classic APIs.  The Billing Plans you are attempting to use are part of the RESTful APIs which use standard oAuth credentials of Client ID and Client Secret.  The REST API reference can be found [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/) and contains information regarding Authentication/Headers as well as other useful information.

Comment: I am trying with request for the header (i.e $headers_array_sub_new = array('clientId'=>'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
             'secret'=>'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx','Accept'=>'application/json'  );